# Рекурсивное добавление в массив

Tags: php, opencart, php7

Почему не срабатывает такая запись?
выдает:

```
Страница недоступна
Сайт пока не может обработать этот запрос

$data['categories'] = array();

    function treeCategory($id, $data){
        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoriesSale($id);
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoriesSale($category['category_id']);

            if ($children){
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    treeCategory($child['category_id'],$data);
                }
            }else{
                return $data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                    'name'        => $category['name'],
                );
            }
        }
    }

    treeCategory(0,$data['categories']);
```

Comment: Навскидку - return должен быть во всех ветках функции. Во- вторых, вот тут мало смысла `if ($children){
                        foreach ($children as $child) {
                            return ...`  - как вы себе представляете цикл из return'ов ?

Comment: смысл такой, если у категории есть подкатегории, то эту категорию не добавлять в массив, а добавить подкатегории у которых нет дочек

Comment: вы формируете переменную $data в else, наверное, ее надо отдавать ? сейчас она просто помирает

Comment: делаю return $data, но все ровно ошибка

Comment: пишите в лог вход выход, смотрите, думайте, что не так